# Granular organisation with Vuex

Tags: javascript, architecture, vue.js, vuex

I'm working on a fairly large project, and I want to break `Vuex` modules into as many parts as possible. For example, I want to separate the `API` functionality from `UI`, keeping the data that comes from the server isolated from the component flags and so.

In the documentation (http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/structure.html), the authors suggest to break everything into `modules`, which is great. The issue comes when I have, let's say, `products` as a page and `products` as data, and I want to keep them separated.

Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
{
  modules: {
    api: {
      products: // ...
    },
    pages: {
      products: // ...
    }
  }
}
```

and be able to access them like `store.api.products` and `store.pages.products`? Am I getting it wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been taking a look at the `vuex` code and I've found this:

```
// retrieve nested modules
const nestedMutations = this._createModuleMutations(module.modules, newNestedKeys)
```

It turns out that you can actually make your `vuex` modules granular by doing:

```
{
  modules: {
    api: {
      modules: {
        products: /* ... */
      }
    },
    components: {
      modules: {
        page: /* ... */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it will result in a state structure like:

[image: Vuex State screenshot]

Comment: There's some discussion around the subject here: http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/4791/granular-organisation-with-vuex